# EWS Search Appointment Body for Substring

Tags: c#, calendar, exchangewebservices, appointment

I need to search for a substring in a user's Calendar appointments. I don't have any other information about the appointment (GUID, Start Date, etc.). I just know that a particular substring is in the body.

I've read a couple articles on how to get the body of an appointment, but they search by the GUID or the subject. I'm trying to use the code below to search for a substring in the body, but I get an error that I can't use the Body in `FindItems`.

Is there a way to do this? Assuming there's no way for me to get any other info from the appointment, is there another approach I can take?

```
        //Variables
        ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Body);

        SearchFilter sfSearchFilter;
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

        foreach (string s in substrings)
        {
            //Search for messages with body containing our permURL
            sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, s);
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, sfSearchFilter, view);

            if (findResults.TotalCount != 0)
            {
                Item appointment = findResults.FirstOrDefault();
                appointment.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, s);
             }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out you are able to search the body, but you can't return the body with `FindItems`.  You have to load it later if you want to use it. So instead of setting my property set to the body, I set it to `IdOnly` and then set the `SearchFilter` to traverse the body of the `ItemSchema`.

```
        //Return one result--there should only be one in this case
        ItemView view = new ItemView(1);
        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

        //variables
        SearchFilter sfSearchFilter;
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

        //for each string in list
        foreach (string s in permURLs)
        {
            //Search ItemSchema.Body for the string
            sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Body, s);
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, sfSearchFilter, view);

            if (findResults.TotalCount != 0)
            {
                Item appointment = findResults.FirstOrDefault();
                appointment.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, s);
                ...
                appointment.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Body));
                string strBody = appointment.Body.Text;
            }
         }
```

Comment: ItemView does not show recurring meeting.