# Exchange web service inbox folder body search not working

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

im working on a EWS search project. Im trying to search emails from Inbox folder by the body.

`SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Body, query);
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = folder.FindItems(filter, iv);`

Another thing that I need its to search by unlimited numbers of schema fields (`ItemSchema.Body`, `ItemSchema.Subject`) in one search. 
When I tried to search on Subject the search worked and when I tried to search on Body the search didn't work.
When i send email with Plain Text body instead of HTML body the search work fine, but most of the emails body are HTML.

In conclusion when I try to search on HTML Body it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your ItemView is trying to return the Body in your results then this is likely the problem.  This answer provides the necessary guidance. [EWS Search Appointment Body for Substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410699/ews-search-appointment-body-for-substring)